# Updating 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

```
    size = 10
    table = [[0] * size] * size
    for iter in range(size):
        table[iter][iter] = 9

    for iter in range(size):
        print(table[iter])
```

I am trying to make all daigonal elements to be 9, but instead it is making all the elements as 9.

Comment: You could write this in a more succinct way, `table = 9 * np.eye(10, dtype=int)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a nested list comprehension to initialize table:

```
size = 10
table = [[0 for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
for i in range(size):
    table[i][i] = 9
for row in table:
  print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
[9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
```